# Error: unrecognized/unsupported device tree compatible list

Tags: kernel, u-boot, device-tree

I need your help. Due to I need Kernel 3.3 for touch screen support for a special device, I've downloaded the Linaro Kernel 3.3-rc3 files. After changing the filesystem from my working Ubuntu-Linaro installation to ext3, the new kernel will boot to the root console, but HDMI and USB is not working...

After some internet hints that HDMI is not working properly with 3.3-rc3 I decided to compile the newest kernel from kernel.org, 3.3-rc6.

Now I'll get following error:

```
U-Boot SPL 2011.12-00001-g8df5795 (Mar 07 2012 - 11:10:22)                   
Texas Instruments OMAP4430 ES2.2                                             
OMAP SD/MMC: 0                                                               
reading u-boot.img                                                           
reading u-boot.img

U-Boot 2011.12-00001-g8df5795 (Mar 07 2012 - 11:10:22)

CPU  : OMAP4430 ES2.2                   
Board: OMAP4 Panda
I2C:   ready
DRAM:  1 GiB
WARNING: Caches not enabled                                                     
MMC:   OMAP SD/MMC: 0                                                           
Using default environment

In:    serial                                                                   
Out:   serial                                                                   
Err:   serial                                                                   
Net:   No ethernet found.                                                       
checking for preEnv.txt                                                         
reading preEnv.txt

** Unable to read "preEnv.txt" from mmc 0:1 **                                  
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0                                                
reading uEnv.txt

** Unable to read "uEnv.txt" from mmc 0:1 **                                    
reading boot.scr

514 bytes read                                                                  
Loaded script from boot.scr                                                     
Running bootscript from mmc0 ...                                                
## Executing script at 82000000                                                 
reading uImage

4767080 bytes read                                                              
reading uInitrd

1877307 bytes read                                                              
reading board.dtb

1747 bytes read                                                                 
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 80200000 ...                             
   Image Name:   Linux-3.3.0-rc6                                                
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)                          
   Data Size:    4767016 Bytes = 4.5 MiB                                        
   Load Address: 80008000                                                       
   Entry Point:  80008000                                                       
   Verifying Checksum ... OK                                                    
## Loading init Ramdisk from Legacy Image at 81600000 ...                       
   Image Name:   initramfs                                                      
   Image Type:   ARM Linux RAMDisk Image (uncompressed)                         
   Data Size:    1877243 Bytes = 1.8 MiB                                        
   Load Address: 00000000                                                       
   Entry Point:  00000000                                                       
   Verifying Checksum ... OK                                                    
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 815f0000                                       
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x815f0000                                     
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK                                                  
OK                                                                              
   reserving fdt memory region: addr=9d000000 size=3000000                      
   Using Device Tree in place at 815f0000, end 815f36d2

Starting kernel ...

Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel.

Error: unrecognized/unsupported device tree compatible list:                    
[ 'ti,omap4-panda' 'ti,omap4430' 'ti,omap4' ]

Available machine support:

ID (hex)        NAME                                                            
0000060a        OMAP3 Beagle Board                                              
0000091a        OMAP3 Devkit8000                                                
00000667        OMAP LDP board                                                  
000006ed        OMAP Logic 3530 LV SOM board                                    
00000882        Logic OMAP3 Torpedo board                                       
00000706        Gumstix Overo                                                   
000005ff        OMAP3 EVM                                                       
000006e1        Pandora Handheld Console                                        
00000472        OMAP3430 3430SDP board                                          
00000c94        Nokia RM-680 board                                              
000007a3        Nokia RX-51 board                                               
000009a0        OMAP Zoom3 board                                                
000007af        OMAP Zoom2 board                                                
000009a1        OMAP 3630SDP board                                              
00000cda        Compulab CM-T3730                                               
00000925        Compulab CM-T35                                                 
00000abe        Compulab CM-T3517                                               
00000a9d        IGEP OMAP3 module                                               
00000928        IGEP v2 board                                                   
00000959        OMAP3 touchbook Board                                           
00000870        OMAP4430 4430SDP board                                          
00000ae7        OMAP4 Panda board                                               
00000898        OMAP3517/AM3517 EVM                                             
00000aa2        OMAP3 STALKER

Please check your kernel config and/or bootloader.
```

I've used the orginal board.dtb and also the version from the kernel tree:

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- omap4-panda.dtb
```

But no success.
I've already the newest uboot from git.linaro.org/boot/u-boot-linaro-next.git, no change.

Who can help?

Answer (score 1):

The existing device tree seems to be causing the problem.
Did you try building it as follows:

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- omap4-panda.dtb
```

You might want to take a look at [**bgamari.github.com/posts/linaro-kernel.html**](http://bgamari.github.com/posts/linaro-kernel.html)

Articles describing the basics of device-tree can be found [**here**](http://omappedia.org/wiki/Device_Tree) and **[here](http://xillybus.com/tutorials/device-tree-zynq-1)**.